# JS Equivalents for jQuery Methods

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am currently removing the `jQuery` dependency from my `AngularJS` project and have come across the following code as part of a spec in my code base:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _$compile_) {
    scope = $rootScope;
    $compile = _$compile_;
    var domElement = '<my-element class="my-class"' + 'ng-class="{' + 'open: myFunction().isOpen === true}"+></my-element>';
    element = angular.element(domElement);
}));

function createComponent() {
    $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    return element.find('my-element');
}
```

I am wondering what the JS equivalents would be for the `angular.element(domElement);` and the `return element.find('my-element');` portions of the code. I know the `angular.element` is just a wrapper for `jQuery` but attempting to use `document.querySelector` (or other methods on `document`) have not been helpful.

Comment: The reason may be because `document.querySelector` return simple dom element(s) but JQuery/Angular return a modified/wrapped representation of it.

Comment: https://github.com/nefe/You-Dont-Need-jQuery

Comment: That particular line of code isn't *selecting* html elements, it's *creating* them. the return statement *selects* an element from the collection of created elements, but it really doesn't need to... it's just 1 element that's already the current one.

Answer (score -1):

There actually aren't any direct javascript equivalents to angular's `angular.element` and `element.find`.

The most closely related things might be `document.querySelector` and `array.prototype.find`, respectively. However, one small, but important difference between the methods provided by angular and their vanilla javascript counterparts, is that the angular methods are supported in a number of browsers that the vanilla javascript methods might not be able to support.